# SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25P02 (current transaction is aborted) with no transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am using JPA with Hibernate to run the following method. The thing is, when FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS (a dynamically created select statement string) is wrong and gives an SQLGrammarException, other unrelated queries (created from unrelated EntityManagers) also stops responding because of "SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25P02" (Postgres) error. Google says this is caused by not rolling back an erroneous query, but there is no transaction here. I also tried rolling back in the catch statement just to be safe, but the problem still occurs.

Thank you

```
public static List<VeMailRecord> getMailVerdicts(HttpServletRequest request, 
        String query, String limit, boolean includeBodies, boolean includeAttachments) {
    String FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS = "SELECT * FROM ve_mail_records ";

    if(query != null && query.length() > 0)
        FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS += "where origin_id = -1 and " + query;
    else
        FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS += "where origin_id = -1";

    if(!FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS.contains("order by")) //Default order
        FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS += " order by receive_time desc ";

    int limitInt, limitConfig;
    try{
        limitInt = Integer.parseInt(limit);
        limitConfig = Integer.parseInt(Config.getProperty("analyst.verdict.limit"));

        if(limitInt > limitConfig)
            limitInt = limitConfig;

        FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS +=  " LIMIT " + limitInt + ";";
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS +=  " LIMIT " + Config.getProperty("analyst.verdict.limit") + ";";
    }

    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    List<VeMailRecord> mailList = null;

    try{            
        mailList = em.createNativeQuery(FETCH_MAIL_VERDICTS, VeMailRecord.class).getResultList();

        if(mailList == null)
            mailList = new ArrayList<VeMailRecord>();//Dummy array list to discriminate 

        //Get attachments of each e-mail
        //VeMailRecord lazy fetches attachments . Force loading attachments
        if(includeAttachments){
            for(VeMailRecord mail : mailList)
            {
                for(AttachmentContainer attachment : mail.getAttachmentList())
                {
                    attachment.getFilename();
                }
            }
        }

        //Remove Bodies
        if(includeBodies){
            for(VeMailRecord mail : mailList)
            {
                mail.setBody("");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while querying in function 'getMailVerdicts'.", e);
        mailList = null;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return mailList;
}
```

Comment: "*but there is no transaction here*" - **Every** statement starts a transaction - even a SELECT statement. So yes, there **is** a transaction going on.

Comment: If so, how can I rollback that transaction? I added the following statement in the catch clause with no success:

if(em.getTransaction().isActive()) 
   em.getTransaction().rollback();

Comment: Not sure how your obfuscation layer knows (or doesn't know) if a transaction is going on. But if you simply call `Connection.rollback()` you should be fine

Comment: In my case I was hitting the issue in the DB console/terminal session.  I had to run `COMMIT` which triggered `ROLLBACK` and allowed the transaction to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

I have encuntered the same error (SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25P02). After seeing the whole log, I saw that there was a previous error that triggered this one and in my case the error is was because there were no grant on the tables. Being in the same transaction the exception is raised